# Creating .msi using Visual & Install (unSigned) and Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, exe, nsis, visual-and-installer

I have both Visual Studio Community 2015 and NSIS 3.01 installed on my Windows 7 PC. I have originally created an .exe using NSIS and then created an .msi (using that same .exe) with Visual Studio. All works as it should, but I was asked to see if there is a plug-in where NSIS can be used within Visual Studio so that the files can be created all under one roof.

Now I was able to locate a plug-in called Visual & Installer (by unSigned) that I was successful in installing. I'm able to create and compile the .nsi within Visual Studio, which creates the .exe for me. The issue/confusion/frustration that I'm running into is how to get that .exe wrapped in an .msi within Visual Studio. When I build my project it seems that the .exe is not being wrapped in the .msi because the application is not being installed. I'm not sure if I'm missing a step, forgot to set a setting somewhere, or if I need Visual Studio to point somewhere specific to pick up the .exe (currently the .exe is not within the Visual Studio folders), etc.

Would appreciate any help/advice/knowledge and I would be most happy to answer any questions or clear up any confusion you may have regarding my issue.

In case you're all wondering...I'm using Notepad++ as my example during my testing.